# What is the difference between forwardingRef vs callback refs in React?

Tags: reactjs

As per the React.js official documentation, the below code is an example of callback refs.

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={props.inputRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(props) {
    //Here, this.inputElement in Parent will be set to the DOM node corresponding to the element in the CustomTextInput
    console.log(this.inputElement);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <CustomTextInput
        inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here, **this.inputElement** in Parent will be set to the DOM node corresponding to the  element in the **CustomTextInput**.

In case of forwarding ref, as per the official document,

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton" data-name="My button">
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
});

//Parent Component
class FancyButtonWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount(props) {
    //Here this.ref will point to button element. Because of this reason, ref.current will give the value of button.
    console.log(this.buttonRef.current.getAttribute("data-name"));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      //Here we are passing the ref to the child component.
      <FancyButton ref={this.buttonRef} data-attr="Hello">
        Click me!{" "}
      </FancyButton>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, in this case, **this.ref** will point to the button element. Because of this reason, ref.current will give the value of the **button**.

Is there any difference between **forwardRef** and **callbackRefs**? We can access the child node's reference from parent in both of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but here are something to think about:
- **callback refs** are used when we need to dynamically set refs.
- **Forward refs** are commonly used when access to child refs are needed.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Apart from this, I am unable to find any other difference between these two.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the difference between the use of *forwardingRef* vs *callback* ref is in the HOC.

if you pass ref prop to HOC then inside HOC you cannot further pass it down to the enclosing component(which HOC wraps) since the props attributes does not store the ref inside it. **ref is not a key** ,see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

so apart form this use case they work in same way.
Hope that helps !!

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the case of the ref callback, you can run side-effects when the ref changes. If you use `useRef`, you can access ref at any time but you will not know when it is set, or run a `useEffect` with the ref as a dependency

Callback refs have more control - they allow you to for example set a state when the ref is set, which will rerender the component when the component mounts, and you can use the ref node to do whatever you need.

In short - generally use `useRef` as it is the simplest. But ref callbacks can give you more control when needed